# DynamoDB Query on multiple hashkeys

Tags: c#, nosql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am struggling with how to model a query in DynamoDB.  Let's use twitter as an example, the question I want to answer is, for the people I follow show me the 20 most recent tweets.

I have 3 Dynamo tables:

```
Users
UserUID - Hash
Handle

Following
UserUID - Hash
FollowingUserUID - Range

Tweets
UserUID - Hash
Tweet
PostedDate - Range
```

What are the steps I need to do to answer the question, for the people UserUID 1234 follows show the 20 most recent tweets.

Steps I have:

Step 1: Get a list of all the people UserUID 1234 follows.

Step 2 (Where I am lost): For that list of Id's show me the 20 most recent tweets.

I am not sure how to structure that second query because I need to filter the hash key on a list of Ids and use a limit and possibly a range filter as well.  Because of that I don't think I can use the BatchGetItemRequest.  Is this possible to do or am I making the problem harder than it needs to be?

Answer (score 3):

> Step 2 (Where I am lost): For that list of Id's show me the 20 most recent tweets.

There is no direct answer to this question since we can't just query "ORDER BY PostedDate"

The only possible solution to do such a complicated mapping in DynamoDB efficiently is by storing data redundant. Of corse you could just get the latest 20 Tweets of each friend and then sort it in your webapp like you already proposed. But guess someone follows 1000 users, that would result into 1000 querys for one user request.

So a possible solution I came up with would be the following:

```
Users
 UserUID - Hash
 Handle

Following
 UserUID - Hash
 FollowingUserUID

FollowedBy
 UserUID - Hash
 FollowedByUserUID

RecentTweetsOfFriends
 UserID - Hash
 PostedDate - Range
 TweetUUID

RecentTweetsOfUser
 UserID - Hash
 PostedDate - Range
 TweetUUID

Tweets
 TweetUUID - Hash
 Tweet
 UserID
 PostedDate
```

Procedure of adding a new tweet to the database:

1. Write the tweet into the Tweets table by creating a new UUID for it
2. Get all users that are following the user that is submitting the new Tweet from the "FollowedBy" table
3. Link the new Tweet in the tables "RecentTweetsOfUser" and "RecentTweetsOfFriends"

For this solution you don't need the "Following" table but I left it in there because it's probably neat to save it for both directions.